# How to change password using old password on parse android

Tags: android, validation, parse-platform, passwords

I have an android app in which user can change his/her password my problem is how i can verify old password of user using parse i have 3 edit text "old password, new password and confirm new password".

I search on parse.com but can't find any solution parse do not fetch data using get password.
 i am doing this

```
String get_confrimpass=currentuser.getpassword();



if(get_confrimpass.replaceAll("\\s", "").equals(current_pass_check))
            {           }
```

Comment: Search better:) [parse.com old password](https://www.parse.com/questions/changing-users-password-issue) "You can try logging in again as the user, using their username (which is available) and the value of the old password they typed in. If the login succeeds, the old password is correct and you can proceed to setting the new one. If it fails, the user will be logged out due to entering a wrong password. - by Héctor Ramos"

Comment: This is very stupid solution. At least they should provide some change password function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try logging them in using there current username and the password that they have given to you. If the loggin is successful the old password is correct. I.e

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername(), currentPassword, new LogInCallback() {  
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {    
        if (user != null) {      
             // Hooray! The password is correct 
        } else {      
             // The password was incorrect 
        }  
   }
});
```

In the example above the 'currentPassword' variable is the text that you would retreive from the 'Old Password' EditText

Comment: If the user was logged in, and types in the wrong "old password" wouldn't the user be logged out (which may be undesired behavior) if they just happen to accidentally typed in the wrong old password?

Comment: No, the current user is only changed if the user being logged in is done so successfully. Otherwise the current user stays the same.

Comment: The only thing about this method is it creates unnecessary session tokens.

Comment: Bit irrelevant as Parse has now been discontinued

Comment: @JayDev only parse.com, this is still very relevant to people using Parse Server

Answer (score 0):

```
final ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
final String userName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername();

ParseUser.logInInBackground(userName, oldPass, new LogInCallback() {
   @Override
   public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
         if (user != null) {
            if (et.length() < 6)
              Toast(getActivity(), "Password is short, Min char 6", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else {
                currentUser.setPassword(newPass);
                currentUser.saveInBackground();
                ParseUser.logOut();
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(userName, newPass, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                    Toast(getActivity(), "Password change", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     } else
             Toast(getActivity(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            } else {
                                new CustomToast(getActivity(), "Old Password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```