# Password Change Parse swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, swift3

I have an app that allows a user to reset their password by putting their old one in a textfield and their new one in the next textfield. But in the old password textfield, the password they entered has to match the one that is registered to the currently logged in user. My app keeps crashing. Can someone help me. Here is the code. An image of the error is here.

[image: ErrorImage]

```
if Password.text == (PFUser.current()?.password)! {

  }else{

 }
```

Comment: Check the value from PFUser.current(), most likely this is nil, which causes the crash when you try to force-unwrap the password. Check this question, it might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522140/parse-pfuser-currentuser-returns-nil-swift  Otherwise, add more of the code, including where you call the code which crashes

Comment: it works if I try to compare password.text to an objectforkey other than password.

Comment: like this works

Comment: if Password.text == PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "email") as! String

Comment: That works, but I cannot connect to password for some reason

Comment: according to the documentation, the password property is only for setting the password: https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFUser.html#/c:objc(cs)PFUser(py)password  so I think you can't use it to read the current password. Same according to this forum post: https://www.parse.com/questions/get-current-users-password-to-compare-it-with-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add exclamation after the text: -

```
if Password.text! == (PFUser.current()?.password)! {

  }else{

 }
```

Edit: -
There is no way to get old password from Parse. Workaround though is.. you can first try authenticate user by giving the password which user has entered.. if authentication is successful then that means the entered old password is correct..  has been [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482566/how-to-change-password-using-old-password-on-parse-android). Although it is android code it gives the required logic.

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername(), currentPassword, new LogInCallback() {  
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {    
        if (user != null) {      
             // Hooray! The password is correct 
        } else {      
             // The password was incorrect 
        }  
   }
});
```

Comment: your Password or PFUser.current() seems to be nil. Try printing these. If Password is null, please check if the outlet is properly connected.

Comment: it works if I try to compare password.text to an objectforkey other than password.

Comment: if Password.text == PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "email") as! String

Comment: That works, but I cannot connect to password for some reason

Comment: which means the password in (PFUser.current()?.password)! is nil, that is why it is crashing when you are unwrapping it with exclamation sign.

Comment: how should i fix it.

Comment: if the password in the (PFUser.current()?.password) is nil, that means you are not getting the old password to be compared. To avoid the crash, you can remove the exclamation sign. But i believe actually you should check why the old password is not coming.

Comment: it works when i remove the explanation point but it says it can't find the password in the database, and I'm entering the correct password

Comment: it seems it is not possible in parse to get old password, https://www.parse.com/questions/checking-if-current-password-inputted-matches-with-the-password-stored-in-parse.

Comment: there is a workaround though.. you can first try authenticate user by giving the password which user has entered.. if authentication is successful then that means the entered old password is correct.. it has been described here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482566/how-to-change-password-using-old-password-on-parse-android

Comment: thanks for marking it an answer, can you please also remove the downvote. thanks in advance

Comment: I Cant remove the down vote. I didnt even mark it. It says, I don't have the ability to do